# Linux permissioning issues

Tags: linux, mysql, file-permissions

I'm trying to create a MySQL table on a different hard drive than the default. I get a permissioning error when MySQL tries to create the file. I think I can boil it down to the following lines of shell commands, which reproduce the error in the shell:

```
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ ls -lha
total 8.0K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql    4.0K 2011-06-06 14:47 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 scott www-data 4.0K 2011-06-06 14:22 ..
-rw-rw-rw- 1 mysql mysql       0 2011-06-06 14:47 globot_tick_spies.MYD
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ sudo sudo -u mysql echo hi > /mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ sudo chmod 664 globot_tick_spies.MYD
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ ls -lha
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql    4.0K 2011-06-06 14:47 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 scott www-data 4.0K 2011-06-06 14:22 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mysql mysql       3 2011-06-06 14:48 globot_tick_spies.MYD
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ sudo sudo -u mysql echo hi > /mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD
bash: /mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD: Permission denied
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$
```

Why can't the user `mysql` edit the file that user `mysql` has ownership and user level permissions for?

**UPDATE**

Okay, the commands above are flawed... I can edit files fine as user `mysql`

```
scott@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ sudo sudo -u mysql bash
mysql@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ ls -alh
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql mysql    4.0K 2011-06-06 15:18 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 scott www-data 4.0K 2011-06-06 14:22 ..
mysql@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ touch test
mysql@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ ls -alh
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql mysql    4.0K 2011-06-06 15:50 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 scott www-data 4.0K 2011-06-06 14:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       0 2011-06-06 15:50 test
mysql@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ echo hi > test
mysql@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ echo hi > test2
mysql@landscapesrv01:/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql$ ls -alh
total 16K
drwxrwxr-x 2 mysql mysql    4.0K 2011-06-06 15:51 .
drwxrwsr-x 3 scott www-data 4.0K 2011-06-06 14:22 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       3 2011-06-06 15:50 test
-rw-r--r-- 1 mysql mysql       3 2011-06-06 15:51 test2
```

So that works fine... But why can't I create my table the way I like?

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `globot_tick_spies` ( `test` datetime NOT NULL ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 DATA DIRECTORY = '/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql';
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD' (Errcode: 13)
```

(Sorry for the confusion above.)

Comment: Please don't double-post questions. Extend one using the [edit] functionality and then delete the other. You also don't have to accept an answer that didn't help (in case you still experience problems). That way your question will likely get more views or attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash thinks you're trying to redirect the output of `"sudo sudo -u mysql echo h"` to `/mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD` instead of sending the full text `"mysql echo hi > /mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD"` through `sudo`.

The redirection is thus happening outside of the `sudo` and therefore as you, `scott`, not as `mysql`.

Try using quotes like this:

```
sudo sudo -u mysql "echo hi > /mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql/globot_tick_spies.MYD"
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I got around that problem. See my edits above...

Answer (score 1):

I used to have similar problems which were ultimately resolved by chowning the mysql-folder itself, i.e.

```
chown mysql /mnt/datadrive/globot/mysql
```

I'm guessing you're not able to create folders as mysql-user?